# Run Time error 9

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have created a workbook which is named "AirHours" & the date from another workbook.  I want to use this workbook throughout the entire project.  The code below works, but I keep getting a run-time error 9 "Subscript out of range".

I'm trying to create a workbook for my report and have my data remain in its original form. The new workbook will be used in a number of modules. The runtime error seems to occur at `SET WSD3=Workbook`.

Maybe I going the wrong way on creating a public workbook.  Thanks for your help.

```
Option Explicit

Public WSD3 As Workbook

Public Sub addNewWorkBook()

Dim NewName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

NewName = "AirHours" & Workbooks("AirTimeWorkBookBeta").Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).Value

Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewName
Set WSD3 = Workbooks("NewName")


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `"` from NewName, so it says `Set WSD3 = Workbooks(NewName)`, tell me if that helps

Comment: `set WSD3 = workbooks.add` then `WSD3.SaveAs NewName` also, you may want to include a path when saving your new workbook

Answer (score 1):

Set WSD3 to your new workbook when you open it

```
Option Explicit

Public WSD3 As Workbook

Public Sub addNewWorkBook()

Dim NewName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

NewName = "AirHours" & Workbooks("AirTimeWorkBookBeta").Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).Value

Set WSD3 = Workbooks.Add

WSD3.SaveAs NewName


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with scott's suggestion, part of the problem is that when referencing workbooks with Workbooks("workbookname.ext") you need to provide the extension, like .xls or .xlsm, so you'll need to update the where you're referencing `Workbooks("AirTimeWorkBookBeta")` to include that workbook's appropriate extension.

You could also get the error if that workbook isn't currently open when the macro is run.
Additionally, make sure that workbook contains a sheet named Data